Prove that a set of cardinality $c$ has $2^c$ different subsets, each of cardinality $c$
I tried to  prove that a set of cardinality $c$ has $2^c$ different subsets, each of  cardinality $c$.
I tried like this:
Let $\mathrm{card}(S)=c$. Then, there exists a bijection $f$ such that:
$$f: P(\mathbb R) \to P(S)$$
so, if I can prove that $\mathbb R$ has $2^c$ different subsets, each of cardinality $c$:
$$A \subset \mathbb R \text{ and } \mathrm{card}(A)=c \implies f(A) \subset \text{S has cardinality } c.$$
I tried to prove that $\mathbb R$ has $2^c$ different subsets, each of  cardinality $c$ like this:
$$\{ [0,x] : x\in  \mathbb R^+ \} \subset P(\mathbb R )$$ and every set of this family of sets has cardinality $c$.
But this family has cardinality $c$, not $2^c$.

Consider two disjoint subsets $A,B\subseteq S$ such that $\operatorname{card}A=\operatorname{card}B=\mathfrak c$. Then $G:\mathcal P(A)\to {x\in\mathcal P(S),:, B\subseteq x}$, $G(u)=u\cup B$ is an injection into a set of subsets of cardinality $\mathfrak c$.

@SassatelliGiulio How can we see that really ther are subsets A and B like this in any set like S. For $\mathbb R$ it is ture. because the cardinality of any interval in $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $c$. But is it really true for any set of cardinality $c$?

Exercise for you.

@SassatelliGiulio I got it. Thanks
